# Selenium Java select div based on nested element text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below HTML structure. Would like to select the label which has

with value 3.x

I have tried below xpath expressions

```
"//label[contains(@class='options')]/div/p[contains(text(),'3.x')]"
"//div[@class='answerOpts']/label[contains(@class='options')]/div/p[contains(text(),'3.x')]"
```

But it didn't work. Received Exception `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:`. Could you please let me know the solution?

HTML structure

```
<div class="answerOpts">
   <input class="optionRadios" type="radio" name="2565" id="answer_9218" value="9218">
   <label class="options searchable" for="answer_9218">
      <div>
         <p>2.x</p>
      </div>
   </label>
   <input class="optionRadios" type="radio" name="2565" id="answer_9219" value="9219">
   <label class="options searchable" for="answer_9219">
      <div>
         <p>3.x</p>
      </div>
   </label>
   <input class="optionRadios" type="radio" name="2565" id="answer_9220" value="9220">
   <label class="options searchable" for="answer_9220">
      <div>
         <p>4.x</p>
      </div>
   </label>
   <input class="optionRadios" type="radio" name="2565" id="answer_9217" value="9217">
   <label class="options searchable" for="answer_9217">
      <div>
         <p>1.x</p>
      </div>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: is it inside iframe? then you need to switch to frame

Comment: No. It is inside normal HTML tags.

Comment: Why don't you add "for" attribute too as it will narrow down the search process.

Comment: I can see that the input has id attribute. Why don't you go from there?

Comment: label tag doesn't have any id. Also could you please provide some example of using for (as you mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some xpath examples how you can get `label` element:

```
//label[normalize-space(.)='3.x']
//label[contains(@class,'options') and .//p[.='3.x']]
//label[contains(@class,'options') and @for and .//p[.='3.x']]
//p[.='3.x']/ancestor::label[1]
//p[.='3.x']/ancestor::label[contains(@class,'searchable')][1]
```

Comment: What is the significance of @for

Comment: It means element has attribute for without specifying value, for your case no any significant just example.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it is Selenium keyword

Answer (score 1):

try with below xpath

.//div/p[text()='3.x']/parent::div/parent::label/preceding-sibling::input[1]